# File size of a JPEG is abnormally big. 39 MBs for 512x512px with Solid color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg

I am working on an, which came to me from a client, which when I was saving as JPEG resulted in a very big file 40 MBs for 1024x1024px. I tried bringing down the resolution, cranking down the quality, save for web, to no avail. I can retrieve the data by flattening it and copying it to new document by I cannot figure out what is wrong with the original image. If anybody has any experience with this or can figure out what it wrong, it would be highly appreciated.

Here is the link of the file: https://app.box.com/s/tv6zg2nu82mv0cpkhkgpnzvmgk6tq4nv
P.S I am using Photoshop 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Metadata and color profile.

Took your **41MB** file.... which contains a mountainous amount of metadata...

[image]

...saved for web **without** metadata and converting to **sRGB**....

Result...

## 2K as PNG24 ... 3K as JPG

[image]

Comment: Well i dindt want to risk opening the image in photoshop. So i had a forensic tool read the file.

Comment: ..meh.. Mac user.. so I pretty much always feel pretty safe against malicious injections within images.. although, I realize I'm really not. :)

Comment: and the machine i used was a newly spun linux inside a rspberry pi which is now reimaged. Maybe im paranoid?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be some embedded data in there, but I am not able to view it as well as remove it How did you manage to save it without the Raw data?

Comment: Found an article that mentions several ways to strip metadata.
https://prepression.blogspot.com/2017/06/metadata-bloat-photoshopdocumentancestors.html
Thanks guys.

Comment: @joojaa, lol. I did wonder why you two dared to download that file. It seems you both got a little rush out of it. 

Comment: @GauravRawat you **can** view the metadata in Photoshop... `File > File Info` and there's a checkbox for `Metadata: None` in the `Save for Web` and `Export as..` dialog windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well the imgage scanline data starts at 41199514. Since the file is 41217256 bytes that means that the image is scanlines are 17742 bytes (17.3 kB) the final jpeg being a bit bigger than that since its comprss dictionary has to fit too So something around 3kB is plausible.

Most of the rest is extended exif metadata. So no your image is not 41 Megas big. It contains something that is not the image.

The document ancestors tag that eats all the memory is a full fingerprint of all files that this file user has touched in the chain of working with it.